# Problem with string.replace() method while evaluating square root

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to create a GUI calculator using tkinter. While my code works fine for all other operations, I'm having trouble evaluating square roots.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root['bg'] = 'grey88'
cal_box = tk.Entry(root, width = 28, bd = 5)
cal_box.place(x = 1, y = 1)

def set_text(text):
    cal_box.insert("end",text)

def clear():
    text = cal_box.get()
    cal_box.delete(0,len(text))

def bspace():
    text = cal_box.get()
    cal_box.delete(len(text)-1)

def enter():
    text = cal_box.get()
    text = text.replace("÷", "/")
    text = text.replace("%", "*0.01")
    text = text.replace("^", "**")
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] == "√":
            sroot = i
            for j in range(sroot, len(text)):
                if text[j].isdigit() == True and (j == len(text)-1 or text[j+1].isdigit() == False):
                    text = text.replace(text[j], text[j] + "**0.5")
                    break
    text = text.replace("√", "")

    clear()
    legal = False
    for i in text:
        if i in "0123456789+-*÷^√.()%":
            legal = True
    if legal == True:
        try:
            set_text(str(eval(text)))
        except (SyntaxError, NameError, TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
            set_text("ERROR")
    else:
        set_text("INVALID INPUT")
```

While the present code does work for expressions like √x, √x+a or a+√x, it breaks when I enter expressions of the form √x+√y. Is there any other way to replace √x with `x**0.5` or `sqrt(x)`??

Comment: You just need to repeat that evaluation in a `while "√" in text:` loop.  By the way, this is NOT the right way to write a calculator.  It would be easier for you to just DO the computations, and not hack your way into `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "√x+√y", try "√x)+√y)" ending the expression in the sqrt with a ")". To do so, replace "√" with "sqrt(". In other words, do `text = text.replace("√","sqrt(")`.

Comment: its what my instincts tell me

Comment: This means a little bit more work for the user, but yeah it works!! Now my √ button enters "√(" by default, so that the user has to enter a ).

Comment: @AyushKumarBiswal Will you do "sin", "cos" and "tan" buttons? basically trig

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are occasionally useful.

```
import re
re.sub('√([a-z]+)', r'\1**0.5', '√x+√y')
'x**0.5+y**0.5'
```